# Xamarin.Forms App always crashes on Android Emulator

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am having an issue with Xamarin.Forms App. When I launch the app on Android Emulator it always crashes.

I tried to look into the output window but there is no information about the app crash at all.

What could be the possible problem ?

Comment: Yeah, output of xamarin crashes is pretty bad. Do you run empty app?

Comment: Use logcat and try to discover what error you are getting. You can monitor specific processes in logcat